# How to write a small Database in Python?

Tags: python, database, python-2.7

I should write a small database in easy way using Python but without SQL or something like that. I have tried that with Class or Dictionary, but unfortunately without success.

```
class DUT(object):
    def __init__(self, id_number, dut, meas_time, end_time):
        self.id_number = id_number
        self.dut = dut
        self.meas_time = meas_time
        self.end_time = end_time

        T001 = DUT(001, "CAF01", 200, 300)
        T002 = DUT(002, "CAF02", 150, 600)
```

> What I have to do ?

I would the same things to create like in excel sheet on the picture. It should be possible to add new sample (DUT) with ID Number, DUT Name, Measurement Time and End Time.

One should be able to add new sample, find/change/overwrite or delete the same. All should be automatised with for example one function or something like that.

[image]

Comment: Use a pandas dataframe an save it to a csv if it's a "small" database? what is the average expected number of lines written per day?

Comment: Writing a database is a massive task, you'd be much better off using one of the many existing supported databases

Comment: Is it a single small table? Use [**`csv`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html). If more than one table use [**`sqlite3`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html). Both are part of Python's library.

Comment: I have your suggestion into considaration...very good ideas.